# Map from JSON to java object with different structure

Tags: java, json, mapping, jackson, dozer

I have a JSON string representing an object, and I want to put its information into a Java object `B` with a different structure. Currently the solution I am taking is creating a Java Object `A` with a structure identical to the JSON object, made the conversion from JSON to `A` using Jackson and later, made the mapping from `A` to `B` using Dozer with XML mappings. Is there anyway to avoid having the `A` objects?

Making it short, currently I have this:

```
JSON--Jackson-->A--Dozer(XML mappings)-->B
```

and I would like to achieve this

```
JSON--???-->B
```

Comment: it depends on the Json and B structure. If you post Json and B java classes -- would be way easier to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may know this already, but Jackson can use loosely structure types like `Map`, or `JsonNode` as target, so you can do, say:

`JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(jsonSource);
Map<String,Object> asMap = mapper.readValue(jsonSource, Map.class);`

and then construct your `B`. Jackson has only limited amount of structural conversions (simple unwrapping), by design, although there is extensive set of scalar conversions (non-structural conversions), so if you do need structural changes it may make sense to use a library that is focused on structural changes.